# Alphanumeric serial with hyphen not working using Go's regex

Tags: regex, go

My ideal regex would return true if the serial matched something like below.

```
A12T-4GH7-QPL9-3N4M
```

Here is what I tried.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    a := "A12T-A12T"
    re := regexp.MustCompile("[a-zA-Z0-9]-[a-zA-Z0-9]")
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString(a))

    b := "A12T-A12T-"
    re2 := regexp.MustCompile("[a-zA-Z0-9]-[a-zA-Z0-9]-")
    fmt.Println(re2.MatchString(b))
}
```

Observe how the variable a is true but as soon as b is called it returns false with the extra hyphen.

My question is, how do I add multiple hyphens in-between alphanumeric characters for this ideal sequence A12T-4GH7-QPL9-3N4M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp you've used matches only 3 (4 in the second example) characters.

If you want to match a set of characters separated by hyphens, you should try a regexp like `([a-zA-Z0-9]+-)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

which translates to code as:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    a := "A12T-4GH7-QPL9-3N4M"
    re := regexp.MustCompile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+-)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString(a))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dMoIOaeUHBa

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
regexp.MustCompile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$")
```

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more alphanumeric
- `(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` -  zero or more occurrences of a hyphen and then one or more alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RzUqdc/1).